# make html buttons not trigger an app.post in node.js

Tags: html, node.js, express

I am using app.post to redirect the user. when the user presses the first button, I do not want them to be redirected, but i still want the first button to send the value. I cant put the `<form>` above the first button, so how do i make the first button not trigger the app.post.

Comment: please provide your the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add attribute type="button" to button tag to remove this behavior.
Example:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname">

  <button>I'll submit form</button>
  <button type="submit">I'll submit form too</button>
  <button type="button">I'm just a button so I don't submit anything</button> <-- It's work
</form>
```

Comment: thank you. this worked. I have one question, what is the difference between type="submit" and type="button"

Comment: Inside <form> tags, button's default type is 'submit' so form will submit form whenever you click, so when we can change type to 'button', it will remove default behavior.
You can see docs in here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp

Comment: wait, how do i make the type="button" button, have a value and submit something without triggering the app.post

Comment: You can try this: `$('button[type=button]').click(function() { $(form).submit(); })`

Comment: Wait but now the first button's value is becoming undefined, is there any way i can make the first button's value not undefined

Comment: I don't understand your mean, can you show me your code?